# SQL Server Agent alternative to VBScript

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, vbscript, sql-server-agent

I have various databases I want to read from, do some stuff with the data (maths, combine strings etc) and write it to another database. All that repeating every day at a certain time.

Currently this is done via an ActiveX-Script (VBScript) in the MS SQL Server-Agent. I want to get rid of the VBScript. If possible, I would like to use the C# Syntax. Windows Task Scheduler is not an option for me.

What is the best practice / best alternative to VBScript in this case?

Comment: SQLSA can also run an external executable (written in C#, if you want) or directly a PowerShell script.

Comment: SSIS with a scripting task

Answer (score 0):

you only write 'do some stuff' so it is not possible to give a more detailed answer but a solution can be to use sql code run by a sql server agent job.

that would not use c# syntax but since you make operation on the data you have to write sql anyway; adding an extra layer just to wrap sql code does not looks like a dependable solution.

an added bonus would be that ther are no external tools, all the job is done by sql server and its components.